# Submit button click in asp.net removes the dropdown list items which gets populated thorugh jquery ajax call

Tags: jquery, asp.net, ajax

I have real hard time in populating select box in asp.net using the jQuery ajax call. The value appears for second on submit button's click event but then disappears, once the page gets refreshed. However this works fine with `<input type="button">`, but I don't want to go that way.

```
function lodaStatedta()
  {
        var methodURL = "Default.aspx/LoadStates";  
        var  parameters ="{}"; //"{'content':'" + $("#ContentTextarea").val() + "', 'autosave':'" + autosaveMode + "'}";
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            url: methodURL,
            data: parameters,
            dataType: "json",
            async: true,
            success: function(data) {
                var listItems = "";
                var states = data.d;
                $.each(states, function (item , index) {
                    //alert(item);
                 listItems += "<option value='" + index + "'>" + item + "</option>"
                });
             $('#mysselect').html(listItems);
             },
            error: function (result) {
            }
        });
    }
```

and calling the method above on submit button click event.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I may be misunderstanding, but you're using input/@type=submit as a button that isn't supposed to submit the form, right? In that case, either place this to FORM tag:

```
onsubmit="return false;"
```

or this at the end of your submit-btn's onclick:

```
return false;
```

so, try that

Comment: Thanks Hari that fixed my problem. and yes i am using submit button  <input type ="Submit"  id="btnSubmit"  value="Submit"/>.i even tried asp.net dropdown list with Enableviewstate=true and referring this drop down by ClientID in jquery code.but even that did not work until i tried your suggestion.so could you share what  was happening with page life cycle ?.what if i want some other controls to get updated on page post back.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I understand this answer at all.
If you didn't want submit form like Hari's said add return false before you submit.
If you don't want reload your select options every time when page refresh you can add one static value in your server side to save data.

Comment: Thanks Hari that fixed my problem. and yes i am using submit button  <input type ="Submit"  id="btnSubmit"  value="Submit"/>.